# How to access Yes/No field of Sharepoint List using Linq?

Tags: linq

I have one list in which there is field with the datatype of Yes/No. I am trying to retrieve data of that field but it is giving me following error :

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.SPQueryable.GetSPFieldValue[T](PropertyMap
>   pm, DataContext dc, SPListItem item, Object entity, JoinPath joinPath)
>   at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , SPListItem ) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator2.MoveNext() at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)

My query is as follows:

```
var query = (from san in db.San
             select san.IsDeclaredCompleted).ToList();
```

So can anyone suggest me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put ToList() method after db.San: `db.San.ToList()`
 [more detail](http://blog.vanmeeuwen-online.nl/2011/03/query-uses-unsupported-elements.html)

Comment: i have tried it.....and only thing changed is the error....